# css property vs angularjs filter

Tags: css, angularjs

In an angularjs app, I need to convert a string to upper case.
I have 2 options which give the same result. However, I would want to know in which scenarios one could be preferred over the other primarily w.r.t. performance.

Option 1 CSS text-transform property

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div style ="text-transform: uppercase">The text-transform uppercase Property</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Option 2 Angularjs filter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="caseCtrl">
    {{txt | uppercase}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('caseCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.txt = "Angularjs uppercase filter";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also you could `{{ txt.toUpperCase() }}` so you won't need any style attribute or filter to make text uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to change the way it is presented when it is a matter of presentation. For example, when you are rendering all headings in UPPER CASE as a stylistic choice.

Use JavaScript to change the text itself when the case has *meaning*. For example when displaying serial codes where people may have entered lower case letters by mistake.

Comment: Apart from matter of style is there any performance aspect which differentiates the two?

Comment: It isn't a matter of style. It is a matter of semantics and accessibility. For example, screen readers will tend to spell out, letter-by-letter, content that is really ALL CAPS but read it out normally if it is just presented in ALL CAPS with CSS.

Comment: Stop trying to do premature optimisation. Pick the option with the correct semantics. If and only if there is an actual performance PROBLEM should you consider hacks to speed things up.